# ASP.NET MVC with REST API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I've been working for years with CakePHP and other PHP based MVC frameworks, but because of a change in jobs I'm now required to use ASP.NET - which is fine. The problem I've got is the development team are all Win Forms devs, so I wanted to open up an API to my MVC apps, using REST, so we could all use the same instance of code to access anything I build.

Problem I've got is, I've been reading a lot on the net, and a lot of people seem to think you should keep the Web API and MVC app in two separate solutions. What I don't get is how I can do this, still using the MVC that I know and love, without ending up doubling up on code?

Any pointers, further reading, or help?

Comment: What code are you concerned about doubling?

Comment: Mainly the models and controllers ... because whilst I know they'll not be identical, they'd be similar.

Comment: Models are an absolute cinch to share. Create a solution that contains 3 projects (at least)--MVC web app, WebAPI app, and model library. Easy-peasy.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to create a project with the shared code (some kind of service layer) and make your MVC and API projects use this project. This way you won't have code duplication.

As an aside, I've used WebAPI and MVC in the same project without any problem. What are the downsides of having them in the same project?

Comment: Well I'm really new to this, but can you have two different auth types in the same project? That was my concern. My way of thinking would be to build the MVC app as normal, then create some sort of routing that would format the responses as JSON? Or am I way off?

Comment: Where would the service layer sit within MVC? Or how would I get it into the same project?

Comment: WebAPI and MVC each have their routes (a webAPI controller and an MVC controller can't share the same route). You can have a single project and different auth types for webAPI and MVC (for example, webapi could use oauth and mvc forms authentication).

Comment: I would create a separate project for the shared code and reference this project from the other two projects.

Comment: Ooh god ... now you're getting into serious MS territory hahah. So ... as I see it, the Models would be the only code that would "really" be properly identical, or at least it should be. So how could the M of MVC be shared by two projects?

Comment: Just create a project with the classes you want to share and add a reference to it from the other projects. Then, from the controller, you only have to call the methods in these classes.

Comment: I think I'm going to have to have a further delve into this. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70129/discussion-between-deej-and-carles-company).